# How to create a list in dart with user defined index values?

Tags: arrays, list, dart

I want to create multidimensional array in Dart as follows:

```
arr[index1][0]=value1;
arr[index2][1]=value2;
```

index1 & index2 will not be 0&1, they should be user defined as required.
How can we define these type of arrays in dart? Please help.

Comment: Use a Map where key is int?

Answer (score 0):

index1 and index2 it is required to be 0 or 1.you can just, if it is not 0 or 1 ask him to type again.